# Html table td: How do I keep width at 0 when changing its border width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've noticed that a table td with width 0px will have an unpredictable width if the right/left border width is changed.

I'm working on an html email builder (using tables) and using an empty td with a right border as a column separator.  The border width can be varied between 0 and 50px using a javascript slider.  However, there is always some width left in the td after setting the border to 0, which messes up alignment in the adjacent columns (tds).  The effect is particularly bad when moving the slider from 50 to 0 in one jump.

It appears to be an artifact of the browser (both Firefox and Chrome) as any td width disappears as intended on page refresh. The same thing can be observed in the browser inspector by typing in different values for the td border width and watching the td width change.

Has anyone else observed this and is there a fix?

```
<table border-collapse="collapse" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-spacing: 0;">
    <tr>
        <td id="main" style="width: 420px; vertical-align: top;">
            <?php foreach ($bodyBlocks as $block) {
                echo $block;
            } ?>
        </td>
        <td id="divider" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 0; padding: 0; border-right: <?= $update->border_width . 'px ' . $update->border_style . ' ' . $update->border_color ?>">
        </td>
        <td id="side" style="width:220px; vertical-align: top; padding: 20px 0;">
            <?php foreach ($sideBlocks as $block) {
                echo $block;
            } ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to put up an HTML snippet so we can see exactly what is being produced? It’s fairly easy to see from what you have given but we can’t see all the settings from that, e.g. border-style

Comment: @AHaworth Thanks...that helped me uncover the problem.  I was trying to make a snippet, and could not reproduce the problem, but also could not remove the problem on my page.  After much trial and error I found out that bootstrap css is causing the problem.  I had though it was inherent to border tds.  I'm not sure how to solve it, but at least I know what the problem is!

Comment: It's the bootstrap border-collapse property

Comment: Problem solved: set  the outer table to border-collapse=separate in html and in css.